# Updating contents in two tables with CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having trouble with updating the content of two tables. The tables are about users, first table is used for login purposes, so it contains username, email and pass, while the second one is used for user details. Both are connected with the ID of the user row. I am having trouble updating these contents. Here is my code, I am new to CI, so basically don't have a clue what goes wrong.

controller:

```
    <?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Student extends CI_Controller {
     public function index()
     {
          $this->load->model('student_model'); 
          $data['all_students'] = $this->student_model->get_student_list();
          $this->load->view('admin_panel', $data);
     }
     public function view_student()
     {
        $this->load->model('student_model'); 
        $data['one_student'] = $this->student_model->get_one_student();
        $this->load->view('view_student', $data);
     }
     public function edit_student()
     {
        $this->load->model('student_model'); 
        $data['one_student'] = $this->student_model->get_one_student();
        $this->load->view('edit_student', $data);
     }
     public function update_student()
     {
        $this->load->model('student_model');
        $data['update_student'] = $this->student_model->update_student();
        $this->load->view('admin_panel', $data);
     }
}
```

View

```
<?php $this->load->view('worker_templates/wheader');
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
$this->load->helper('form');
echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
echo form_open('student/update_student');

foreach ($one_student as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<div class='col-md-6'>";
    echo form_label('Name&nbsp', 'worker_name');
    echo form_input('Name', $value['worker_name']);


    echo form_label('Role&nbsp', 'role');
    echo form_input('Role', $value['role']);

    echo form_label('Email&nbsp', 'worker_email');
    echo form_input('Email', $value['worker_email']);
    echo "<br/><br/>";

    echo form_label('Phone&nbsp', 'phone');
    echo form_input('Phone', $value['phone']);
...
```

This is very long, So I'm not copying it all to bore you.

Model:

```
public function get_one_student() //used to show a student, also to display data of one student for update
     {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('workers');
        $this->db->join('worker_details', 'worker_details.student_id = workers.worker_id');
        $this->db->where('worker_id', $_GET['id']);
        $q = $this->db->get();
          return $q->result_array();
     }
    public function update_student()
     {
    $data = array(
        'worker_name' => $this->input->post('worker_name'),
        'worker_email' => $this->input->post('worker_email'),
        'role' => $this->input->post('role'));
    $this->db->update('workers', $data); //first table
    $data2 = array(
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'date_of_birth' => $this->input->post('date_of_birth'),
        'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
        'university' => $this->input->post('university'),
        'speciality' => $this->input->post('speciality'),
      ... //again, very long, not including it all
        );
    $this->db->update('worker_details', $data2);//second table
     }
```

Comment: You're missing a where when you update it should say ->where('id', $SomeIDYouPassedTotheMethod);

Comment: Nope, does not work with just that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your update_student() function in model. please post worker_id in hidden from your html form and correct function as below.

```
public function update_student()
     {
    $data = array(
        'worker_name' => $this->input->post('worker_name'),
        'worker_email' => $this->input->post('worker_email'),
        'role' => $this->input->post('role'));
    $this->db->where('worker_id', $this->input->post('worker_id'));
    $this->db->update('workers', $data); //first table
    $data2 = array(
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'date_of_birth' => $this->input->post('date_of_birth'),
        'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
        'university' => $this->input->post('university'),
        'speciality' => $this->input->post('speciality'),
      ... //again, very long, not including it all
        );

    $this->db->where('worker_id', $this->input->post('worker_id')); 
    $this->db->update('worker_details', $data2);//second table
     }
```

Comment: added this to my form:
$hidden = array('worker_id' => '$_GET[id]', 'student_id' => '$_GET[id]');
echo form_open('student/update_student', '', $hidden);
Also added the corrections you mentioned
Still does not work, no data is updated

Comment: whatever you are sending first check that is not '0' or 'Null'. and where condition is needed for update record. `$this->db->where('worker_id', $this->input->post('worker_id'));`

Comment: All fields are being checked, I added that line you posted, does not update data in the DB.

Comment: Could you share your DB tables and form html source which you are posting to controller.

Comment: i observed your code. please create hidden input field inside form

Comment: There is a hidden input field. This
$hidden = array('worker_id' => '$_GET[id]', 'student_id' => '$_GET[id]');
echo form_open('student/update_student', '', $hidden);
equates to 
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="student/update_student">
<input type="hidden" name="worker_id" value="$_GET[id]" />
<input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="$_GET[id]" />